# SQl and SSRS download for practice

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to practice on both SQL and SSRS for practice and struggling to find what I need to download?

I want to create some queries to practice building some reports in SSRS.

Is this possible and if so which download is the best?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server 2014 Express with Advanced Services (SQLEXPRADV) has reporting services and can be downloaded from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx)

Comment: Hi, after filling everything in it takes me to the msdn evaluation centre. There is no download there but states to log in here to access the downloads if you are an MSDN subscriber?

Comment: I'm not a subscriber and I then get the following screen https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/manage/bb980931.aspx which tells me I have no details but can't sign up as they have suspended the service?